# How can I make a value modified in a child component available to the parent?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

This is my simple component:

```
<template>
    <div class="input-group colorpicker-component">
        <input type="text" v-model="color" class="form-control"/>
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i></i></span>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            value: {type: String},
        },
        data() {
            return {
                color: this.value,
            }
        },
        mounted: function() {
            var self = this
            $(self.$el).colorpicker()
        },
        beforeDestroy: function() {
            $(this.$el).colorpicker('hide').colorpicker('destroy')
        }
    }
</script>
```

It gets initiated like this:

```
<color-picker v-model="imageBackground"></color-picker>
```

How do I get back the color that I have picked inside of component in the parent? This component can be used many times in parent.

How can I keep the parent updated with value picked in color-picker component?

I've run into a problem with Bret's suggestion:

What happens is I am using color picker a jquery plugin so I have to do this inside mounted:

```
    mounted: function() {
        var self = this
        $(self.$el).colorpicker()

        $(self.$el).on('changeColor', function(event) {
            self.color = $(self.$el).colorpicker('getValue')
        })

    },
```

I register on changeColor event listener and wire it up with color data property. That works fine the input gets correct value and this.color gets correct value, but the problem is that If I pick color value by using color picker plugin it is not not broadcast to the parent, parent sees it only if I type it by hand or if I after I picked it with color picker add a space at the end of value already there, then it gets back to parent correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$emit` it.

```
<input type="text" v-model="color" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)" class="form-control"/>
```

By default, `v-model` listens for an `input` event. But this can also be customized. This is covered in the docs [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Customizing-Component-v-model).

In order to additionally set the color when the `colorpicker` changes the color, emit the value from the `changeColor` event.

```
$(self.$el).on('changeColor', function(event) {
  self.color = $(self.$el).colorpicker('getValue')
  self.$emit('input', self.color)
})
```

Comment: hi when I emit it back, will this imageBackground data property get the new value? That is what I use to initalize with, so I need that to be updated with any changes.

Comment: cool, justed tested it and it worked, vue is beautiful :) thanks Bert for another helpfull answer!

Comment: Hi Bret, I run into a problem with your solution, it worked when I typed in something by hand inside input element, but not if its set there by code. Can you take a look at my updated question.

Comment: great, that did it! Approving your answer now